# MongoDB Compass disconnects immediately using ssl but works fine from command line

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongodb-compass

I am trying to set up mongodb with ssl, but am having problems connecting through mongodb compass.

Running mongodb as:

> mongod

works fine and I can easily connect to it through both compass and command line.

When running the server with ssl however, as: (I'll set up a config file for this later)

> mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile mongo.pem --sslCAFile rootCA.crt --bind_ip 127.0.0.1

I get problems connecting through compass. I give compass a self made CA cert (the same one the server uses), a key, and a cert signed by the CA cert made from the key. The result is the following error on compass:

> Could not connect to MongoDB on the provided host and port

and the following is logged on the mongod server:

> 2019-05-25T13:34:24.730-0400 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52246 #3 (1 connection now open)
>   2019-05-25T13:34:24.793-0400 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:52246 (0 connections now open)
>   2019-05-25T13:34:24.795-0400 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52247 #4 (1 connection now open)
>   2019-05-25T13:34:24.832-0400 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:52247 (0 connections now open)

As you can see, there is no ssl error, or any error given for that matter. Compass connects, immediately disconnects, and then tries one more time before giving up.

On the other hand, connecting to the ssl required server on command line works fine using the same certs as compass:

> mongo --ssl --host 127.0.0.1 --sslPEMKeyFile compass/compass.pem --sslCAFile rootCA.crt

The only difference is that compass.pem is generated from:

> cat compass.crt compass.key > compass.pem

instead of giving the crt and key files directly to compass.